# Prisma Query engine library for current platform "debian-openssl-1.1.x" could not be found

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, openssl, prisma

I have a NodeJS/NestJS project consisting of multiple microservices. I've deployed my postgres database and also a microservice pod which interact with the database, on an aws kubernetes cluster. I'm using Prisma as ORM and when I exec into pod and run

> npx prisma generate

the output is as below:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (4.6.1 | library) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 1.32s
You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```

but when I call an API to create an object in my postgres db by the prisma ORM, I get the error below in the microservice pod:

```
error:  PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid `prisma.session.create()` invocation:


Query engine library for current platform "debian-openssl-1.1.x" could not be found.
You incorrectly pinned it to debian-openssl-1.1.x

This probably happens, because you built Prisma Client on a different platform.
(Prisma Client looked in "/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node")

Searched Locations:

  /usr/src/app/node_modules/.prisma/client
  C:\Users\MOHSEN\Desktop\cc-g\cc-gateway\cc-gateway\db-manager\node_modules\@prisma\client
  /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client
  /usr/src/app/node_modules/.prisma/client
  /usr/src/app/node_modules/.prisma/client
  /tmp/prisma-engines
  /usr/src/app/node_modules/.prisma/client


To solve this problem, add the platform "debian-openssl-1.1.x" to the "binaryTargets" attribute in the "generator" block in the "schema.prisma" file:
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native"]
}

Then run "prisma generate" for your changes to take effect.
Read more about deploying Prisma Client: https://pris.ly/d/client-generator
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34316:13)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34737:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PrismaService._executeRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35301:22)
    at async PrismaService._request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35273:16)
    at async AppService.createSession (/usr/src/app/dist/app.service.js:28:28) {
  clientVersion: '4.6.1',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

Also this is *generator client* in *schema.prisma* file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "linux-musl", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}
```

Before that I had the same problem but the error was mentioning about *"linux-musl"* like below:

```
Query engine library for current platform "linux-musl" could not be found.
```

although I was using linux-musl in the binary target in generator block.

but after lots of research I found that I should not use *alpine* node in my docker file and instead I used ***buster*** and my docker file is as below:

```
FROM node:buster As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build db-manager

FROM node:buster as production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

I think the problem is that, the prisma query engine could not be found because it is searching wrong locations for platform specific query engine. So, I tried to provide the locations that query engine files are located in my pod, as ***ENV*** variables in the deployment file as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db-manager
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db-manager
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db-manager
          image: image-name
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3002
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "3002"
            - name: DATABASE_URL
              value: db url
            - name: KAFKA_HOST
              value: kafka url            
            - name: PRISMA_MIGRATION_ENGINE_BINARY
              value: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x
            - name: PRISMA_INTROSPECTION_ENGINE_BINARY
              value: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/engines/introspection-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x
            - name: PRISMA_QUERY_ENGINE_BINARY
              value: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node
            - name: PRISMA_FMT_BINARY
              value: /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-debian-openssl-1.1.x
```

but it doesn't work and the error still happens when prisma try to execute a *create query*. I would be very appreciated if anyone could help me. Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug in prisma when used in aws deployment?

thanks for any comments or guides about that.

Answer (score 8):

Try to update to 4.8.0 Prisma version, and set the binaryTargets property in `schema.prisma` file to:

```
(...)

binaryTargets = [
  "native",
  "debian-openssl-1.1.x",
  "debian-openssl-3.0.x",
  "linux-musl",
  "linux-musl-openssl-3.0.x"
]

(...)
```

Don't forget to run `yarn prisma generate`

Comment: Why do you suggest to enable ALL binary targets at once?

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me

```
FROM node:18.16.1-slim

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000

# add this line
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
```

Installing the `build-essential` and `libpq-dev` packages helped me. Those support building native dependencies like the pg package that Prisma uses to interact with PostgreSQL databases.